# How do I make two linux partitions share a swap partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, swap

I have two Ubuntu linux partitions, and each has its own swap space. Is it possible to make them use the same swap space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to edit your /etc/fstab files to list the same partition as swap for both. Beware however that if you hibernate one and then start the other the "hibernated" state will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can both use the same swap space. Just make sure the entry for them in `/etc/fstab` is the same for each distribution or you'll get errors about invalid swap signatures.